# Android deeplink - don't show intent chooser popup, force open app

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest, deep-linking, android-intent-chooser

I want to open my app from browser, when user opens any link that my app handles. So I'm using deeplinking. Here's my code in manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name=".ColorCaptureActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_color_capture"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter android:label="DeepLink">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.somelink.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Everything fine, but when I click on the link, android shows intent chooser, where displayed all apps that can handle this intent. I understand it's the default behaviour, but is there a way to not show the chooser popup and open my app directly?

Comment: Is `www.somelink.com` your own domain and your own Web site?

Comment: No. But can you explain me for two cases? E.g. it's my own and in second case it's not my website.

Comment: "No" -- then you cannot force the user to use your app. For domains that you own and control, use https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing App Links to set your application as the default handler for the links.

Refer: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#app-links-vs-deep-links

Comment: Do not post link-only questions.

Comment: Why not? The question is already old, but the person gave the right answer.